# I got stuck creating an if statement to check two variables

Tags: java

First I will write what I want to do:

User choose flight by ID, after that if the user has a promo code enter it.

This is Flight objects:

```
    Flight flight1 = new Flight(1, "Moscow", "Belgrade", 300, 600, 850, "gC49");
    Flight flight2 = new Flight(2, "Paris", "Dortmund", 250, 290, 400, "soe4");
    Flight flight3 = new Flight(3, "Podgorica", "Nis", 25, 40, 80, "sx33");
    Flight flight4 = new Flight(4, "London", "Miami", 600, 1500, 2500, "zcl3");
```

That `gC49` at the end of first object is promo code. if the user enters that code, it is printed that he has a discount, if that code is incorrect, he does not have a discount.

I tried that on this way:

On this part of code user choose one flight by ID:

```
   System.out.println("Choose one flight by ID: ");
    int userChoiceFlight = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
        if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                    + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());
        }
    }
```

---

In this part of the code, the user asks if he has a promo code, if so, he enters it, if that code matches the code from the flight object he has chosen, he should write a message that he has a discount.

```
 System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no) ");
    String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

    if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter promo code");
        String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Flight tempFlights : flightList) {
            if (userPromoCode.contains(tempFlights.getPromoCode())) {
                System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Promo code is not valid!");
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (yesNo.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("Find one, you have no discount!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
    }
```

This is main code:

```
if (userPromoCode.contains(tempFlights.getPromoCode())) {
```

**Error is:**

The promo code from the first object is valid over each object, so if the user enters the promo code of the first object he has a discount on each flight.

**What I need:**

User choose one flight by ID, that flight has some promo code, if the user enters that promo code they get a discount.

**Example:**

User pick ID number 3, that is this flight:
`Flight flight3 = new Flight(3, "Podgorica", "Nis", 25, 40, 80, "sx33");`
When a program asks a user for a promo code, he should enter `sx33` for discount, otherwise message is `no discount for you` for example.

I tried to loop like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size();) {
            if (userPromoCode.contains(flightList.get(i).getPromoCode())) {
```

But its stil same.

Comment: Save the instance in `tempUserChoiceFlight` somewhere in a variable/field to indicate "this is the flight the user has chosen". Then use it later to access the promo code.

Comment: you need to save the object which user have selected for the flight input, after the user enters the promo code you need to compare the previously stored object's promo code.

Comment: How I achieve that? I understand what are you trying to say but idk how to realize that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a separate for loop to iterate through the list, you always start from the first "Flight" object. So, according to your code, `tempFlights.getPromoCode()` will always be the promo code of the first flight. What you need to do is compare the promo code enters by the user with the already selected flight.

So, instead of using two for loops, you can do something like this.

```
System.out.println("Choose one flight by ID: ");
           int userChoiceFlight = scanner.nextInt();
           scanner.nextLine();

          for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
            if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
                System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                    + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());

               System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no) ");
               String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();

               if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
                 System.out.println("Enter promo code");
                 String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();

                if (userPromoCode.contains(tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromoCode())) {
                    System.out.println("Cool you have discount!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Promo code is not valid!");
                    break;
                }
        
            } else if (yesNo.contains("no")) {
                System.out.println("Find one, you have no discount!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it was all because two for loops? Ahh I see it now, thanks

Comment: Yes, because when you use a separate for loop to iterate through the list, you always start from the first "Flight" object. So, according to your code, `tempFlights.getPromoCode()` will always be the promo code of the first flight. What you need to do is compare the promo code enters by the user with the already selected flight.

Comment: Yeah, I understand in my head what I need to do but didnt know how to realize it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

While iterating the flightList, you are getting the *id* and *destination* from the list. If you can get the *promocode* of that particular flight, it could help you.

```
String promo = ""; // declaring a global variable outside the for loop so you can use it later
for (Flight tempUserChoiceFlight : flightList) {
        if (userChoiceFlight == tempUserChoiceFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You flight from: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getFrom()
                    + " to: " + tempUserChoiceFlight.getTo());
            promo += tempUserChoiceFlight.getPromo(); // getting the correct promocode 
        }
    }
```

As you now have the correct promocode of the flight the use wants, you can ask the user with his promocode, the one which he has and compare the two. Like this:

```
 if (yesNo.contains("yes")) {
        ...
        String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        if(userPromoCode.equals(promo)) { 
       ...
```

You need not iterate over the flightList again as you have already stored the correct promocode.